# Question regarding reporting medical insurance, interest income and my address because of part-year stay in the US

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance, turbotax

I am seeking urgent assistance with my US tax filing (with TurboTax) for 2018 concerning part-year residency. I lived in the US between Jan-August and left the country for good thereafter. Keeping this in mind, how do I answer the following questions:

1. State of Residence on the last day of the year - I picked a foreign address for this question and indicated Indiana as the “other state” of residence which is where I lived. Is this correct?
2. Medical Insurance - I only had employer provided insurance for half the year and didn’t need any insurance going forward since I no longer lived in the country. However, TurboTax offers no option that matches my case. The closest is “Resident in a foreign country…” for the penalised months. Is this the correct option then because from what I understand, this pertains to US citizens or permanent residents and I was a resident-alien in the country.
3. For State Taxes, I need to report how much of my earned interest income was acquired while living in Indiana. Let’s say I earned $500 interest throughout the year and about $200 of it was earned while I was in the US. How do I report the rest? Do I indicate only the part of income earned while I still lived in Indiana or attribute the entire $500 amount as earnings in this state?

Please help me navigate these, I would sincerely appreciate some help here!